# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer in KendoUI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui, signalr, kendo-grid

I have a KendoUI grid that renders an image as part of a template, looking like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UnitDetails)
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(ds => ds
                            .Ajax()
                            .Read(read => read.Action("Get", "FleetMonitor"))
                            .AutoSync(true)
                            .PageSize(3)
      )
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:auto;" })
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(270);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(250);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(150);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(550);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(25);
              columns.Template(p => { }).ClientTemplate(" ").Width(100);
          })
      .ClientRowTemplate(Html.Partial("_ClientRowTemplate", Model).ToHtmlString())
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable())
```

But, whenever I load the page the grid crashes with the following exception:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

So, I googled for it and it lead me to SO, which gave a suggestion to the problem (My controller):

```
public ActionResult Get([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string tag)
{
    UnitContract[] listOfUnitsFromService = UnitClient.GetListOfUnits(false, tag, true);
    var cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Company.Name.UnitTagCookie");

    Model = new FleetMonitorModel
                {
                    UnitDetails = GenerateUnitDetails(listOfUnitsFromService.ToList()),
                    Tags = GetAvailableTags(),
                    Refresh = true,
                    SelectedTag = GetTagFromCookie(cookie)
                };

    var jsonResult = Json(Model.UnitDetails.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

    return jsonResult;
}
```

So, could anyone provide some insights to this, and a possible workaround? :) I should mention that it works and renders the template if I change the grid initalization-part from this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.UnitDetails)
...
```

To this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<UnitDetailsModel>()
```

However, doing so breaks some other functionality in my grid. To be more specific; it prevents my SignalR-js from working for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Try placing this setting in the web.config of your project:

```
    <configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```